# After setting OnPreparedListener to VideoView, it never gives callbacks to onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) method in Devices with in build Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

In my nexus-5 the progress indicator which i have set on video view never dismisses.
My code is as

```
 PlayerActivity extends Activity{
    private VideoView mVideoView;
      private OnPreparedListener mListner=new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            //dismiss progress indicator

            }
        };


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.playback_activity);
  mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
  mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(mListner);
 // show progress dialog on videoView
 ...
 ...
```

}

Comment: Do you somewhere set a media on the video view? Because the listener is only invoked when the media is loaded and is ready to go.

Comment: I set url to video view as mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));